# How Wireshark is able to pick network traffic from within Windows10 coming from WSL2

Tags: windows-10, wireshark, wsl2, c++, c

My task is to create 2x programs written in C/C++ which can communicate with each other from within WSL2 and Windows 10. I'm able to send traffic from WSL2 to Windows 10, however
I cannot manage to pick network traffic from Windows 10 side coming from WSL2 with a simple sniffer program written in C (on my own PC), however I'm able to see on 2x WireShark opened, (one in Windows 10 and one in WSL2) the UDP messages I'm trying to send to the IP address of WSL2 in Windows.

- I've tried putting ports in inbound rules of my FireWall (no result).
- I've tried setting my network interface into promisc mode in WSL2 (no result).
- I've tried setting the example [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windowswsl-interop-with-af_unix/) (no result in WSL2, however it works under WSL1, but I'm not interested in WSL1).
- I've tried setting up [this project](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/install/mingw) (no result).
- I've tried setting up the communication using [USB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) (no result, I had a message related to 3rd party firewall blocking the specified port for communication, but didn't come to resolution about it).
- I've tried the [WSL Networking guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking) (no result).
- I cannot create bridge, since its prohibited in my corporate environment, I cannot forward ports.

I'd like to understand how WireShark is able to sniff the traffic and possibly implement it on my side in a simple communication WSL2 send message ---> Windows receive msg.

Comment: Looks like your well-formatted question from Stack Overflow got ... mangled a bit when copied/pasted over here.  Suggestion for the future - You can use the "Edit" feature on the old question to copy the full Markdown over.  That will prevent formatting mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark uses a custom driver – Npcap – to capture traffic. (It was previously known as WinPcap.) See [Developing software with Npcap](https://npcap.com/guide/npcap-devguide.html).

Npcap is only needed for network sniffing (packet capture); you shouldn't need it for normal communications between host and VM – regular UDP sockets should be enough for that.

Comment: I already tried normal UDP also AF_UNIX sockets. The problem is the corporate environment, 3rd party firewall is blocking most of the things on the PC. I think WireShark has something to do with sniffing the traffic on a kernel level, so literally passing the rules. Placing anything related to rules in the Firewall also doesn't take effect.